# Chrome fails to render document library of sharepoint online correctly

Tags: document, library, chrome

Chrome fails to render document library of sharepoint online correctly.

Chrome cut off half of the first folder in my doc library view. F5 (refresh) solves the issue, but it is annoying and my IT service desk are unable to solve it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Chrome problem, try to clear cache and cookies, it sometimes help.

How-to: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop